# CouchDB error on POST to _temp_view

Tags: couchdb

I try make temporary view on CouchDB:

```
curl -X POST  'http://127.0.0.1:5984/blog/_temp_view' -d '{"map":"function (doc) {  emit(null, doc )  }"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Basic admin:admin'
```

and have error:

```
{"error":"unknown_error","reason":"function_clause"}
```

in CouchDB log:

```
[Fri, 11 Sep 2015 14:30:02 GMT] [error] [<0.20879.6>] 

function_clause error in HTTP request
[Fri, 11 Sep 2015 14:30:02 GMT] [info] [<0.20879.6>] Stacktrace: [{base64,b64d_ok,
[bad],
[{file,"base64.erl"},{line,364}]},
{base64,decode,2,
[{file,"base64.erl"},{line,266}]},
{base64,decode,1,
[{file,"base64.erl"},{line,117}]},
{couch_httpd_auth,basic_name_pw,1,
[{file,"couch_httpd_auth.erl"},
{line,50}]},
{couch_httpd_auth,
default_authentication_handler,1,
[{file,"couch_httpd_auth.erl"},
{line,65}]},
{couch_httpd,authenticate_request,2,
[{file,"couch_httpd.erl"},{line,401}]},
{couch_httpd,handle_request_int,5,
[{file,"couch_httpd.erl"},{line,316}]},
{mochiweb_http,headers,5,
[{file,"mochiweb_http.erl"},{line,94}]}]
```

When I make temporary view in Futon

```
function (doc) {  emit(null, doc )  }
```

It's working good.

I have CouchDB 1.6.1 on Ubuntu 14.04

How I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's because that's not the way CouchDB handles authorization, either you try to run it without the Authorization header if you allow it or you use FTP-like login:

```
curl -X POST  'http://admin:admin@127.0.0.1:5984/blog/_temp_view' -d '{"map":"function (doc) {  emit(null, doc )  }"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/security.html#authentication

Comment: Thanks for reply! But I use virtual host :  domain cblog.local mapped to /blog/_design/blog/_rewrite , and use angular application in design doc (/blog/design/_blog) So, my angular application not have access to CouchDB root (http://localhost:5984/) How I can make authorization in this case?

Comment: Then I would suggest that you don't use  temporary views, they are for testing and developing and do not scale.

Comment: If you look at the link I've posted there is a section about cookie authentication that you could use for your application, but I still think temporary views should be avoided.